# How ListNode && dummyNode works?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Hi I have difficulty on understanding how ListNode && dummy node works.

Suppose we are given the head of the list. When we declare ListNode dummy = head, and we are not touching dummy node in the rest of code, but only changeing the node head, I'm wondering that why dummy node still has the reference to the modified node head? Suppose the code is:

```
ReverseList(ListNode head){
ListNode dummy = head;
while(head != null){
...
//we are not doing anything with dummy here
...
}
return dummy.next;
}
//if we change head, the dummy will also change(why?)
```

I really appreciate any explanation!

Comment: Because that's how pointers work... is this homework?

Comment: Simply put you've used the `dummy=head` on a probable *reference type* by using the equal to `=` `assignment` operator. This essentially makes dummy and head the safe object as they point to the same memory address.

Comment: I understand how = works, if I say int x = 5; int y = 10; x = y; y = 15; and eventually my x is 10, it's not changing the value afterwards, but in listnode, we declare node A = node B, we only change B, the node A also changed, this is the point I don't understand